# updating data in mysql with combobox radiobuttons and button c#

Tags: c#

So here is the thing i have an option to select data in the combobox when i select it i can chose with radio buttons frrom 1 to 5 how much i will rate it and when i select radiobutton and press button it should update the data in mysql but idk what is wrong here..

the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
            string Query = "UPDATE filmi.film SET '" + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem + "' = 1";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@film", this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("Ocena oddana!");
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Replace This:

```
string Query = "UPDATE filmi.film SET '" + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem + "' = 1";
```

With This:

```
string Query = "UPDATE filmi.film SET film = @film";
```

**2.** Replace This:

```
myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
MessageBox.Show("Ocena oddana!");
while (myReader.Read())
{
}
```

With This:

```
cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**EDIT:**

if you want to update or increment your column value by 1 for each update

Try this:

```
string Query = "UPDATE [TableName] SET [COLUMNNAME] = [COLUMNNAME]+1";
```

Comment: yes but how would i update the data so it will add +1 to the database so lets say the data is `MOVIE2014` and the rating is now `0` when i press this button the rating will be `1`

Comment: the 2nd point where u told me to replace the code when i replaced it didnt it was a problem in conneciton but i put it back as it was and changed the rest and it works now thanks alot sir